# "The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL." on Azure's app with Only HTTPS redirect activated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, https, .net-4.6.2

I've a ASP.NET MVC (.NET 4.6.2) app run within Azure.
I've configured the DNS and the Only HTTPS redirect.

If I type http://myapp.mydomain.com on browser, it correctly redirect to https://myapp.mydomain.com

BUT, sometimes I got some error from Global's Application_Error() method of MVC, which say "The requested resource can only be accessed via SSL.". And the SourceURL param is http://myapp.mydomain.com

How can it be if the HTTPS redirect is activated? How can I simulate this event?

Answer (score 0):

The `RequireHttps` attribute does automatically attempt to redirect to `https://your-url`.

So,

Add this to your Controller methods and it behaves as expected.

If you redirect to the Index action on the controller from a ***HTTPS*** protocol, it will redirect to ***HTTP***.
It only allows ***HTTP access*** to the Index ActionResult.

```cs
[RequireHttp]  
public ActionResult Index() {  
return View();  
}
```